# How can I make my JavaScript BlackJack game have one function to add up the values of the cards for the player and dealer?

Tags: javascript, blackjack

I'm struggling to create my own Blackjack game using JavaScript. I didn't have any images for cards so I followed a YouTube tutorial and downloaded a folder from the user's GitHub page and copied that part of the code but otherwise, I would like to try to create my own version of Blackjack. Each card image in the folder I'm using is titled "A-C.png", "2-C.png" etc. with C, D, H, S being Clover, Diamonds, Hearts and Spades respectively. Here is the HTML code first that I have:

Next, here is the JavaScript code that I've created. I also created a function called getValueDealerCards() which is very similar to the getValuePlayerCards() function, only replacing playerCards.forEach() with dealerCards.forEach(), playerCards with dealerCards as a parameter in the function call and playerHand with dealerHand when adding up the values on the last line.

The code I have is working and displaying the cards that are dealt properly but it's a little too long and I don't like having two separate functions just to add up the values of the player and dealer cards respectively.

I would also like to add code to keep track of who wins each round until there are no cards left in the deck too but for now, I wanted to focus on creating a function to add up the values of the cards for the player and dealer first. I also tried using for loops but using two separate forEach methods in the getValuePlayerCards() and getValueDealerCards() was the only attempt that seemed to be working. I appreciate any suggestions and advice for improving my project.

```js
var hidden; 
var winner; 

var canHit = true; 
var nextTurn = true; 

var playerScore = 0; 
var dealerScore = 0; 

var playerHand = 0; 
var dealerHand = 0; 

let playerCards = []; 
let dealerCards = []; 

let cards = ["A-C", "2-C", "3-C", "4-C", "5-C", "6-C", "7-C", "8-C", "9-C", "10-C", "J-C", 
"Q-C", "K-C", "A-D", "2-D", "3-D", "4-D", "5-D", "6-D", "7-D", "8-D", "9-D", "10-D", "J-D", 
"Q-D", "K-D", "A-H", "2-H", "3-H", "4-H", "5-H", "6-H", "7-H", "8-H", "9-H", "10-H", "J-H", 
"Q-H", "K-H", "A-S", "2-S", "3-S", "4-S", "5-S", "6-S", "7-S", "8-S", "9-S", "10-S", "J-S", "Q-S", "K-S"]; 

startGame(); 

function startGame() {
    shuffleDeck(cards); 
    startTurn(); 
}

function startTurn() {
    dealCardstoDealer(); 
    dealCardstoPlayer(); 
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
    for(i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length); 
        let temp = deck[i]; 
        deck[i] = deck[j]; 
        deck[j] = temp; 
    }
    console.log(deck); 
}

function dealCardstoDealer() {
    let cardImg = document.createElement("img"); 
    hidden = cards.pop(); 
    dealerCards.push(hidden); 
    cardImg.src = "./cards/" + "BACK" + ".png"; 
    document.getElementById("DealerHiddenCards").append(cardImg); 
    getValueDealerCards(card, dealerCards); 
    do {
        let card; 
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img"); 
        card = cards.pop(); 
        dealerCards.push(card); 
        cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png"; 
        document.getElementById("DealerCardsShow").append(cardImg); 
        getValueDealerCards(cards, dealerCards); 
        } while(dealerHand < 17);
    console.log(`The dealer currently has ${dealerHand}`); 
}

function dealCardstoPlayer() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img"); 
        card = cards.pop(); 
        playerCards.push(card); 
        cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png"; 
        document.getElementById("PlayerCardsShow").append(cardImg); 
        getValuePlayerCards(card, playerCards); 
    }
    console.log(`The player currently has ${playerHand}`); 
}

function getValuePlayerCards(card, playerCards) {
    let cardValueArray = []; 
    playerCards.forEach(getCardFirstValue);
function getCardFirstValue() { 
    cardValue = card.slice("-"); 
    cardInteger = cardValue[0]; 
    cardValueArray.push(cardInteger); 
    cardValueArray.forEach(checkValue); 
}
function checkValue(cardInteger) {
    if(cardInteger == "A") {
        cardrealValue = 11; 
    } else if(cardInteger == "J"|| cardInteger == "Q"|| cardInteger == "K") {
        cardrealValue = 10; 
    } else {
        cardrealValue = parseInt(cardInteger); 
    }

    playerHand+=cardrealValue; 
}
function getValueDealerCards(card, dealerCards) {
    let cardValueArray = []; 
    playerCards.forEach(getCardFirstValue); 
function getCardFirstValue() {
    cardValue = card.slice("-"); 
    cardInteger = cardValue[0]; 
    cardValueArray.push(cardInteger); 
    cardValueArray.forEach(checkValue); 
}

function checkValue(cardInteger) {
    if(cardInteger == "A") {
        cardrealValue = 11; 
    } else if(cardInteger == "J"|| cardInteger == "Q"|| cardInteger == "K") {
        cardrealValue = 10; 
    } else {
        cardrealValue = parseInt(cardInteger); 
    }

    dealerHand+=cardrealValue; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Black Jack Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyAttemptBlackJack.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="RoundScore">Round Score</p><br>
    <p id="DealerScore">Dealer's Score:</p><br>
    <div id="DealerHiddenCards"></div>
    <div id="DealerCardsShow"></div><br>
    
    <p id="PlayerScore">Player's Score:</p><br>
    <div id="PlayerCardsShow"></div><br>
    <button id="HitButton">Hit</button>
    <button id="StayButton">Stay</button><br>
    <p id="GameResult">Game Result</p>
    <script src="MyAttemptBlackJack.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You left out the definition of `getValueDealerCards()`.

Comment: @Barmar I apologize, I didn't want to include the entire function `getValueDealerCards()` since it was very similar to the `getValuePlayerCards()` function. I only replaced a few parameters and it runs the same way as the  `getValuePlayerCards()` function.

Comment: But we need to see how they're different so we can help write a single function that does both.

Comment: @Barmar I added the `getValueDealerCards()` function.

Comment: `getValueDealerCards(card, dealerCards); ` --> `card` is undefined. Is this your actual code? It doesn't work.

Comment: @trincot My apologies, there was a line that I forgot to include in the `getValueDealerCards` and `getValuePlayerCards` functions. The error that you mentioned should not happen anymore.